# Disable "Unable to open <URL>. Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server" error

Tags: microsoft-excel, connection, webserver, runtime-error

I've been having this problem in Excel 2003, but maybe it's also present in earlier versions.

I have an Excel spreadsheet that imports data using a web query, which connects to a web page hosted in my company's servers. The data changes day by day, and so does the URL, so I have a macro that takes care of the URL change and automatically refreshes all data every hour.

It works fine, but sometimes the company's server crashes. When my macro tries to connect to the server and it's down, the following message box appears: "Unable to open . Cannot locate the Internet server or proxy server". Excel stops the macro whenever this happens and it won't continue until I manually click on the Accept button. This is a big problem, since the data has to be constantly updated.

I've looked for many ways to solve the problem. I've tried adding an error handler, "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" at the top of the macro and I also did [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/218153), but to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
Sub ChangeURL()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim NewURL As String
    Dim Today As String
    'M1 contains today's date formatted as text
    Today = Range("M1").Value
    NewURL = "URL;http://www.example-url.com/data/date=" & Today
    'Change the table's URL so it gets today's data
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1)
        .Connection = NewURL
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    'Re-execute the macro after an hour has passed
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "Change", , True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Is there a way to truly disable these message boxes?

Comment: I'm not sure how you wrote the macro, but it sounds like a "try/catch" type situation.  If it is written with VBA I think you need to add an "on error goto .......somewhere" clause...maybe pause it for a certain amount of time, or just exit.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141571   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028288/properly-handling-errors-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick.

```
Sub MyMacro()

    code...code...code
    ....trying to connect....
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    code...code...code
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    . . .
    Resume <or Exit Sub>
    . . .

End Sub
```

FROM: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141571

Comment: I've tried to do this but to no avail. The error message still apears.

Comment: If you copy the code for your macro (without the website if you like) we might be able to replicate the problem and give you a more specific answer.  This sounds like a good challenge.

Comment: The inability to connect must not be considered an "error"...hmmm.